# How to display launchpad animation in mavericks 10.9

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

How to display launchpad animation for application downloaded from some websites.

If you will download application from app store , you will get following animation at first time.

[image]

There is no entry for this animation in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db`

Comment: If you don't get traction here, try apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: You won't get that with non MAS apps. Stuff downloaded manually starts with the quarantine flag also.